# (Jsoup) How to parse a specific column and row?

Tags: java, html-table, jsoup

Basically I have this bus schedule table:

```
<table id="smsBusResults" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
            <tbody><tr>
                <th>Linha</th>
                <th>Hora Prevista</th>
                <th>Tempo de Espera</th>
            </tr>
                            <tr class="even">
                <td>        <ul class="linhasAssoc">
                <li><a target="_self" class="linha_502" title="" href="/pt/viajar/linhas/?linha=502 ">502 </a></li>
                </ul>
    &nbsp;MATOSINHOS M</td>
                <td><i>17:09</i></td>
                <td>2min</td>
            </tr>
                            <tr class="even">
                <td>        <ul class="linhasAssoc">
                <li><a target="_self" class="linha_201" title="" href="/pt/viajar/linhas/?linha=201 ">201 </a></li>
                </ul>
    &nbsp;VISO - C2</td>
                <td><i>17:13</i></td>
                <td>5min</td>
            </tr>
                            <tr class="even">
                <td>        <ul class="linhasAssoc">
                <li><a target="_self" class="linha_203" title="" href="/pt/viajar/linhas/?linha=203 ">203 </a></li>
                </ul>
    &nbsp;CAST. QUEIJO</td>
                <td><i>17:18</i></td>
                <td>10min</td>
            </tr>
                            <tr class="even">
                <td>        <ul class="linhasAssoc">
                <li><a target="_self" class="linha_502" title="" href="/pt/viajar/linhas/?linha=502 ">502 </a></li>
                </ul>
    &nbsp;MATOSINHOS M</td>
                <td><i>17:20</i></td>
                <td>12min</td>
            </tr>
                            <tr class="even">
                <td>        <ul class="linhasAssoc">
                <li><a target="_self" class="linha_201" title="" href="/pt/viajar/linhas/?linha=201 ">201 </a></li>
                </ul>
    &nbsp;VISO - C2</td>
                <td><i>17:22</i></td>
                <td>15min</td>
            </tr>
                        </tbody></table>
```

"Linha" means "Bus No. and Dest. Name", "Hora Prevista" - "ETA", "Tempo de Espera" - "Waiting Time".

For example, the first bus is the bus 502 with destination to Matosinhos, he should arrive at 17:09, and the waiting time is 2 mins.

How do I print only the first bus' name? (col 1, row 0)?

**What have I tried...**

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.stcp.pt/pt/itinerarium/soapclient.php?codigo=ACRD1").get();


    ArrayList<String> nomesLinhas = new ArrayList<>();
    Elements smsBusResults = doc.select("smsBusResults");
    Elements filas = smsBusResults.select("tr");
    Elements colunas = smsBusResults.select("td");

    for (int i = 0; i < filas.size(); i++) {
        Element fila = filas.get(i);
        Elements cols = fila.select("td");

        System.out.println(cols.get(1).text());
    }

}
```

}

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please update your question to explain what you've tried.

Comment: If you want to get the element with id `smsBusResults` you'll have to use `doc.select("#smsBusResults");` or better yet `doc.select("#smsBusResults").first();` since there is only one.

Comment: You can try out css selectors here http://try.jsoup.org I've already made a selector that retrieves the column you're interested on here http://try.jsoup.org/~ePyjQgDLIVPrsMxo5BdpVwahPAs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first get `doc.select()` method. If your document has name doc, then the following code will bring you row 0 col 1:

```
Element row = doc.select("tr").get(0);
Element col = row.select("td").get(1);
String text = col.text();
System.out.println(text);
```